# Drupal 7 Commerce keeps giving "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]" errors

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

The actual error is

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbaname.cache_views' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE {cache_views} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 165 of C:\Me\dev\xampp\htdocs\dbname\includes\cache.inc).

I got this error earlier on an recently installed drupal commerce site, after trying some fixes I gave up and reinstalled it. So now on a fresh install of Drupal Commerce KickStarter without the sample store this error keeps getting thrown. 
I had this problem with cache_views, cache_views_data and another.

I found some fixes on the web to do with Dropping the table and then creating it again. There is a weird side to this, if you try to create the table directly it can't as its already there, but you can't see it!

Anyway weird drop/create thing aside, anyone know the source of this issue?

running  PHP v.5.6.11
Drupal Commerce Kickstarter 7.x-2.11

cheers

EDIT:
Appreciate the answers that came in already, but i'm thinking its more a XAMPP issue. The XAMPP PHP log file was throwing [warnings] regarding InnoDB (sorry deleted the file already), which appears related to the issue above. I've now reinstalled XAMPP and the InnoDB warnings have cleaned up. going to try a fresh commerceKickstart now and see where its at. cheers

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur because of an older Drupal version. Download the latest Drupal 7 version and install it and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, such as cache_views and cache_views_data, etc., used for cache bin in Drupal. so  please try to reinstall views module correctly, this issue would be fixed.